# How to get the child text using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="div1">
 <span>Hi how are you</span>
 <div><span class="ts">i need this question</span></div>
 <span class="m1">some content</span> 
</div>
```

I need to get the text of class ts using child parent relationship.Please refer the below jquery code which return true but i dont know how to get the text . Please correct my code

```
$("#div1 span").hasClass( "ts" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#div1").find("span.ts").text();
```

This should do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like. You need to use class selector instead of using hasClass. The [class selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) will check the elements with given class. The [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function will return you the text of the span you get with selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Fk9ua/)**

```
$("#div1 span.ts").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var txt = $("#div1 div span.ts").text();
alert(txt);
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fLP6V/) Or you even get them directly using class like

```
var txt = $('span.ts').text();
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fLP6V/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

```
$("#div1 span.ts").text();
```